# Random height on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have divs with random heights. However my random height function in the ng-style gets called only once, and applies the same random height to all divs

Here is my html:

```
<div id = "{{result.myId}}"ng-repeat="result in results" ng-style = "resultBox" ng-click="loadDetails(result.myId)">
    <div ng-style="setImage(result.miThumbnail)"></div>
    <h5>{{result.name}}</h5>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.resultBox = {
            backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
            height: $scope.randomHeight(200)+'px',
            position:'relative',
            textAlign:'center',
            verticalAlign:'top',
            width:'260px',
            display:'inline-block',
            margin:'10px',
            borderRadius:'5px'
        };

 $scope.randomHeight = function(max){
            var height = Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+1);
            return height;
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `$scope.randomHeight(200)` runs only once and reuse over and over again. Try converting `$scope.resultBox` to a function.

```
$scope.resultBox = function(){ 

        return {
            backgroundColor:'#ff0000',
            height: $scope.randomHeight(200)+'px',
            position:'relative',
            textAlign:'center',
            verticalAlign:'top',
            width:'260px',
            display:'inline-block',
            margin:'10px',
            borderRadius:'5px'
        };

       }
```

Also change your html to call this function: `ng-style="resultBox()"`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq4qW/)

Comment: Thank you. Side question: How can I adjust for the margin gaps, since the height is random, the gap between margins just stays open

Comment: @William Falcon: adjust your `margin:'10px'` depending on the random height. Since this is a function, you can do something like `var height = $scope.randomHeight(200)`, and use the height to calculate margin. (if this is what you need)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a function:

```
<div id = "{{result.myId}}"ng-repeat="result in results" ng-style = "resultBox()" ng-click="loadDetails(result.myId)">
    <div ng-style="setImage(result.miThumbnail)"></div>
    <h5>{{result.name}}</h5>
 </div>
```

And

```
   $scope.resultBox = function() {
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        height: $scope.randomHeight(200)+'px',
        position:'relative',
        textAlign:'center',
        verticalAlign:'top',
        width:'260px',
        display:'inline-block',
        margin:'10px',
        borderRadius:'5px'
    };

    $scope.randomHeight = function(max){
        var height = Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+1);
        return height;
    };
```